# How to concatenate over 2 ndarray(variable) in loop (one of these is EMPTY in first loop )

Tags: python, matlab, numpy-ndarray

I want to achieve this function in Python like Matlab

in matlab, the code is

```
A = [];
for ii = 0:9
    B = [ii, ii+1, ii**2];
    C = [ii+ii**2, ii-5];
    A = [A, B, C];
end
```

but in Python, use np.hstack or np.concatenate, **the ndarray must have same number of dimensions**

if the A in first loop is empty, the code will make mistake as following:

```
for ii in range(10):
    B = np.array([ii, ii+1, ii**2])
    C = np.array([ii+ii**2, ii-5])
        if ii == 0:
            A = np.hstack([B, C])
        else:
            A = np.hstack([A, B, C])
```

and, that is my Python code, B and C are **variable**, not **repeat** the ndarray, plz don't close my question!

```
for ii in range(10):
    B = np.array([ii, ii+1, ii**2])
    C = np.array([ii+ii**2, ii-5])
    if ii == 0:
        A = np.hstack([B, C])
    else:
        A = np.hstack([A, B, C])
```

but, i think it a little troublesome and unreadable.

how can i rewrite it?(It's better to use only one line of code)

Comment: What should the result be?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what the result Should be - I think this is close

```py
import numpy as np
q = np.arange(10)
bs = np.vstack((q,q+1,q**2)).T
cs = np.vstack((q,q**2,q-5)).T
a = np.hstack((bs,cs))
```

Or maybe:

```py
a = np.hstack((bs,cs)).ravel()
```